# Regarding search resources on the CKAN main search bar

Tags: solr, ckan

I just started building a project on CKAN and would like some information regarding the search operation on CKAN. For example, I uploaded a CSV dataset which contains some information regarding different members. I am able to search for the different members on the dataset search bar but when I search the same thing on the main search bar I could not get the same result. Maybe it is not iterating through the resources inside the dataset? If this is not intended functionality, how I can implement this?

Comment: You are able to search in dataset search because it is using the **datastore_search** [action][1] that allows you to search the data from the resource. The main search which provides (simple/advanced) search modes will search only for the name or title of the dataset or you can use fielded search by providing Datasets Attributes as title:dataset_title or author:author_name from the metadata. 


  [1]: https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.7.3/maintaining/datastore.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.